# Displaying pictures from html file using tcp based web server

Tags: c#, html, .net

I am working on a project which essentially consists of creating a basic single thread web server that has to have basic functionality for forms, displaying images, text, etc.  I am currently at a point where I can display the html pages fine, except images do not display correctly (they show the alt tag instead of the picture itself).  As this is my first time doing this, and I am basically figuring it out as I go, I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");                   
sb.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/html");
sb.AppendLine("Content-Disposition: inline");
sb.AppendLine("Content-Length: " + file.Length);
sb.AppendLine("Connection: close");
sb.AppendLine();

List<byte> response = new List<byte>();
response.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
response.AddRange(file);
byte[] responseByte = response.ToArray();

ns.Write(responseByte, 0, responseByte.Length);
```

This is the code I have so far that prints HTML to the screen, however this ends with images showing as the alt tag with a small picture of a picture icon beside it.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: The `Content-Type` header must match the content. An image is not `text/html` but you're only statically sending that one content type. Send the appropriate one when you send images.

Comment: The issue is that I am trying to pass the image inside of an html file, and if i change the content type then my html wont display properly

Comment: Are you trying to build your own web server? I am not sure what the **file** variable contains in your code. But a web server will not serve html and images in a single response (unless the img tags in your HTML has all the data embedded as base64). Usually, it is just the HTML, and the browser parses it and issues additional requests that your HTML page depends on (like JS, CSS, img href sources, etc). Since you are building your own server, you will have to handle those calls as well.